# Embedding Spring Boot Admin UI in an iframe

Tags: spring-boot-admin

We have an existing application where we monitor all microservice's kafka events and reference data. Came around SpringBootAdmin and wanted to integrate this in our existing monitoring application.

Added SpringBoot Client Starter dependency in all our microservices and added SprigBoot Admin Server Starter dependency to monitoring application. The problem am facing is am not able to access our previous UI. The UI is taken over by SpringBoot Admin UI.

**So, wondering is there any possibility to include this admin ui as a separate component in our UI/or can we embedded it as a iframe. Or is it possible to access SpringBoot Admin UI on some click event.**

Answer (score 0):

The springboot admin console does run on different port than usual application. You can definitely have a link in your main web application that will redirect user to admin application. My concern was on iframing the admin application in another application. For iframing an application into another application, there are 3 primary conditions to be fulfilled

1. both application must have same protocol.
2. both application must have same domain.
3. both application must have a same port.

Trickiest thing in above is port number. But as from your question it appears that you own both the application, you can resolve this but using some proxy servers like nginx to have both application satisfying all 3 conditions and thus iframing it.